# Get unique ID count with Start time and End time

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark

I have this Dataframe

```
Date  ID
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      A
1      B
2      A
```

In which start date and end date was calculate and find the unique count of the ID It's simply a person come is date 1 and end_date is 1 are:

```
Date Id
1    A
1    A
1    B
```

so the unique user is 2  and the total count of the record is 3

I want to create this Dataframe with `column Start_date` and `End_date` and unique count of the `ID`

```
Start_date   End_date  Unique
  1             1        3
  1             2        2
  1             3        3
  1             4        4
  2             2        2 
  2             3        3 
  2             4        4
  3             3        1
  3             4        3
  4             4        2
```

How to do that?

Comment: How do you caculate `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: Do you want a python or SQL answer?

Comment: I want to know how you get `start_date` and `end_date` from `date`. Just plain English logic will do. Show us the code if you can.

Comment: It's simply a person come is date 1 and end_date is 1 are:                 
Date Id
1    A
1    A
1    B                                                                                                                 so the unique user is 2  and the total count of the record is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,IntegerType

def date_ranges(start_date,end_date):
    return list(range(start_date,end_date+1))

date_ranges_udf = F.udf(date_ranges, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D'),(1,'A'),
    (2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'A'), (1,'B'),(2,'A')], ["Date", "ID"])

df_start_end_dates = df.select(
    F.min(F.col('Date')).alias('min_date'),F.max(F.col('Date')).alias('max_date')
).withColumn('start_date',F.col('min_date')).select(
    'start_date',
    F.explode(
        date_ranges_udf(F.col('min_date'),F.col('max_date'))
    ).alias('end_date')
)

cond = [F.col('Date') >= F.col('start_date'), F.col('Date') <= F.col('end_date')]

df_start_end_dates.join(
    df,cond
).groupBy(
    'start_date','end_date'
).agg(
    F.countDistinct('ID').alias('Unique')
).orderBy(
    'start_date','end_date'
).show()
```

which results

```
+----------+--------+------+
|start_date|end_date|Unique|
+----------+--------+------+
|         1|       1|     2|
|         1|       2|     2|
|         1|       3|     3|
|         1|       4|     4|
+----------+--------+------+
```